# Problem with the responsiveness of my site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have to make a site which presents a menu of desserts for a restaurant. I used JS to make a flip-book animation. My site should mainly be adapted for phones. The problem is that on the phone when I "open" the card, the left part of menu is off the screen and I cannot scroll to get it.
Can anyone help me?

```js
var currentPage = 0;

$(".book").on("click", ".active", nextPage).on("click", ".flipped", prevPage);

$(".book").hammer().on("swipeleft", nextPage);
$(".book").hammer().on("swiperight", prevPage);

function prevPage() {
  $(".flipped")
    .last()
    .removeClass("flipped")
    .addClass("active")
    .siblings(".page")
    .removeClass("active");
}
function nextPage() {
  $(".active")
    .removeClass("active")
    .addClass("flipped")
    .next(".page")
    .addClass("active")
    .siblings();
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scene {
  width: 560px;
  height: 793px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.page {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: 1.5s -webkit-transform;

  transition: 1.5s transform;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    0% 0%,
    100% 100%,
    from(#ffffff),
    to(#cccccc)
  );
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    from(#fff),
    to(#ccc)
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #fff, #ccc);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff, #ccc);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.page.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.page.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.page.flipped:last-of-type {
  z-index: 1;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="scene">
    <article class="book">
      <section class="page active">
        <div class="front">
          <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/559x751.jpg?text=Page%20A"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/559x751.jpg?text=Page%20A%20Back"></p>
        </div>    
      </section>
      <section class="page">
        <div class="front">
          <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/559x751.jpg?text=Page%20B"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/559x751.jpg?text=Page%20B%20Back"></p>
        </div>    
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an English site, please check-out https://french.stackexchange.com

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no French StackOverflow. You will need to translate your question to English in order for it to be answered here.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but you're calling the "hammer" function on jQuery, but that function doesn't exist. Are you missing a plugin?